# Incorrect data in MyISAM database due to concurrency

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency, atomic, myisam

#### Problem

I have a webpage that does the following (the code is much simplified to show only relevant code.

```
mysql_query("insert into table1 (field1) values ('value')");
$last_id = mysql_insert_id();
$result = mysql_query("select * from table1 t inner join ... where id = $last_id");
write_a_file_using_result($result);
```

It happened, that the file was created using a different data set than what I found in the table row.

The only explanation I have is:

- call1: page was called 1. time with data set 1.
- call1: data set 1 gets inserted for connection 1 but gets not committed to the table.
- call2: page was called 2. time with data set 2
- call2: data set 2 gets inserted for connection 2 and `mysql_insert_id` returns **the same value**
- call1: file is generated with date set 1
- call2: file cannot be written, because it already exists

Result: The file is generated with data set 1 while the table row contains data row 2.

#### Config

mysql 5.0.51b

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  (...)
```

#### Question

I know that MyISAM does not support transactions. But I really expect that it is impossible to insert two rows and get twice the same id inserted, so that the row can be overwritten.

**Is MyISAM unsafe to this point or is there another explanation that I overlook ?**

#### Note

I know the mysql extension for php is outdated, but I did not yet rewrite the application.

Comment: Concurrency issues should not affect autoincrement ids in any way, and I've __never__ heard of any incident where duplicate autoincrement ids have been allocated... that would be a pretty fundamental problem, and would surely have been experienced by other users before now... the problem is more likely to be somewhere in your own code

Comment: Auto_increment should not assign the same numbers. You can also add PRIMARY KEY to your id column to make sure that it stays unique.

Answer (score 1):

> Is MyISAM unsafe to this point

No. `mysql_insert_id` guaranteed to return the right value only.

> or is there another explanation that I overlook ?

Most likely. Check your code.

Comment: I checked the whole code, and cannot find an update statement that could have modified the data. I also store the data along the md5 hash of the data, an can disproof that way that the data was modified afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't heard about id issues in MyISAM. 
You can try to set link identifier when calling last_insert_id, for example

```
$link = mysql_connect(...);    
mysql_query("insert into table1 (field1) values ('value')",$link);
$last_id = mysql_insert_id($link);
$result = mysql_query("select * from table1 t inner join ... where id = $last_id",$link);
write_a_file_using_result($result);
```

Comment: Do you think that it can give issues when the link identifier is not set ? I have only one connection in each script, so there should not be a possible problem. Or do I miss something ?